# AVSpeechSynthesizer delegates are not calling in iOS 11

Tags: ios, iphone, ios11, avspeechsynthesizer

Here is my code for text-to-speech. Everything is working fine below iOS 11. But in iOS 11 delegate methods are not being called.

`AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate` is set accurately. (As it is working below iOS 11)

On button tap

```
AVSpeechSynthesizer *synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc]init];
synthesizer.delegate = self;

AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:stringToSpeech];
[utterance setRate:AVSpeechUtteranceDefaultSpeechRate];
[utterance setPitchMultiplier:1];
[utterance setVolume:1];
utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"en-US"];
[synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
```

These are delegate methods I have implemented.

```
-(void)speechSynthesizer:(AVSpeechSynthesizer *)synthesizer didFinishSpeechUtterance:(AVSpeechUtterance *)utterance {
    NSLog(@"finished");
}

-(void)speechSynthesizer:(AVSpeechSynthesizer *)synthesizer didStartSpeechUtterance:(AVSpeechUtterance *)utterance{
    NSLog(@"Started");
}
```

Did someone face this issue?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I m testing on iOS 11.0.3, with Xcode 9.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `synthesizer` object must be a property for that to work :).

Either make your `AVSpeechSynthesizer` instance, which is `synthesizer` like so:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVSpeechSynthesizer *synthesizer;
```

or like this with readwrite.

```
@property (readwrite, strong, nonatomic) AVSpeechSynthesizer *synthesizer;
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: @MZubairShamshad which type of property usage solved your problem among the mentioned 2 types?

Comment: @AanchalChaurasia `@property (strong, nonatomic) AVSpeechSynthesizer *synthesizer;` did work for me

Comment: @MZubairShamshad Thanks for your response.

Comment: I will Upvote for sure, once i will get confirmation that its working fine.

Comment: Worked for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I write this by Swift. finaly i found The delegate method must marked as public then i got the callback.

Comment: This is not a answer, this should be comment